# Adding a new column based off a lookup table in R

Tags: r, merge, lookup

I have a table:

```
ID  pheno   x1   x2   x3 
ABC 1       .43 .634 .542
BCD 0       .542 .42 .43
LOP 1       .235 .46  .78
```

etc

I have another table, where every ID in this table is male

```
ID 
ABC 
LOP
etc
```

I want to match those IDs in the second table and then add a column to table 1 indicating whether or not the IDs appear in table 2

Output:

```
ID  pheno   x1   x2   x3  sex
ABC 1       .43 .634 .542 1
BCD 0       .542 .42 .43  0
LOP 1       .235 .46  .78 1
```

I have tried

```
newtable <- table1[ifelse(table1$ID %in% table2$V1, table1$SEX <- 1, table1$SEX <-0),]
```

But the sex column just outputs 0s for every line.

Your help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you need MALE==1 and FEMALE==2, this is a solution you could use:

```
table1$sex <- (!table1$ID %in% table2$ID) + 1
table1

#>    ID pheno    x1    x2    x3 sex
#> 1 ABC     1 0.430 0.634 0.542   1
#> 2 BCD     0 0.542 0.420 0.430   2
#> 3 LOP     1 0.235 0.460 0.780   1
```

---

Where:

```
table1 <- read.table(text = "ID  pheno   x1   x2   x3 
ABC 1       .43 .634 .542
BCD 0       .542 .42 .43
LOP 1       .235 .46  .78", header = TRUE)

table2 <- data.frame(ID = c("ABC","LOP"))
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks! This gives me a boolean TRUE/FALSE. How would I turn this into 1/2?

Comment: check my lastest update. I've added a `+` in front

Comment: Amazing, thanks again. If I wanted 1/2 instead of 0/1 how would i do that?

Comment: 1 = MALE or 1 = FEMALE?

Comment: 1 = MALE, many thanks. For now I've just done table1$sex[table1$sex == 0] <- 2

Comment: okay, check the update